# Por que debo retornar un objeto y no puedo retornar lo que yo quiera en react-typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

tengo un custom hook para el uso de formularios, tengo una interface DataForm, se la asigno al custom hook de la forma useForm{} e inicio el objeto.

En el useForm recibo la data enviada es decir el estado inicial, posterior a eso tengo el handler que actualiza el estado, el handler lo uso en unos input y en un par de select asi que lo llamo con un evento de onChange

Lo curioso es que cuando en el useForm intento regresar un arreglo con los formValues y el handlerInputChange, me tira un error que no entiendo a que se refiere, pero si retorno los mismos elementos como un objeto entonces no hay ningun problema

Aqui el codigo

```
import React from 'react'

import './citesForm.scss'
import useForm from '../hooks/useForm'

interface DataForm {
  name: string;
  last: string;
  date: string;
  time: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

const CitesForm = () => {
  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm<DataForm>({
    name: '',
    last: '',
    date: '',
    time: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  })
  return (
    <div className="cites__form-wrapper">
      <h2 className="subtitle">Creacion de cita</h2>
      <form action="#" className="cites__form">
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="name"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Nombre
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="cites__input"
            name="name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={formValues.name}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="last-name"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Apellidos
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="cites__input"
            name="last-name"
            onChange={ (e) => { handleInputChange(e) } }
            value={formValues.last}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="date"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Día
          </label>
          <select
            className="cites__input"
            name="date"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={formValues.date}
          >
            <option value="">Selecciona un dia</option>
            <option value="14-12-1995">14-Dec</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="time"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Hora
          </label>
          <select
            className="cites__input"
            name="time"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={formValues.time}
          >
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="14">14:00</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="email"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Correo
          </label>
          <input
            type="mail"
            className="cites__input"
            name="email"
            onChange={ (e) => { handleInputChange(e) } }
            value={formValues.email}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="cites__input-wrapper">
          <label
            htmlFor="phone"
            className="cites__label"
          >
            Teléfono
          </label>
          <input
            type="tel"
            className="cites__input"
            name="phone"
            onChange={ (e) => { handleInputChange(e) } }
            value={formValues.phone}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary cites__submit">Crear Cita</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CitesForm
```

Y el useForm

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react'

const useForm = <T extends Object>(initState: T) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initState)
  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      [target.name]: target.value
    })
  }
  return [
    formValues,
    handleInputChange
  ]
}

export default useForm
```

El error :

```
D:/www/citas/src/components/CitesForm/CitesForm.tsx
TypeScript error in D:/www/citas/src/components/CitesForm/CitesForm.tsx(39,13):
Type 'DataForm | (({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void)' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'DataForm' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Type 'DataForm' provides no match for the signature '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void'.  TS2322

introducir el código aquí

    37 |             className="cites__input"
    38 |             name="name"
  > 39 |             onChange={handleInputChange}
       |             ^
    40 |             value={formValues.name}
    41 |           />
    42 |         </div>
```

Y vuelvo a mencionar, el error no ocurre si hago el return en el useForm como un objeto

```
{
  formValues,
  handleInputChange
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda aclarar que es lo que esta pasando, mil gracias

Answer (score -1):

Yo te recomendaria utilizar una libreria para formularios, yo utilizo esta con react typescript, [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/), es muy simple de usar, y hace todo lo que quieres, la idea no es reinventar la rueda.